# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype') at registerCustomInspection

Tags: javascript, typescript, ethereum, hardhat

I ran the command `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.ts --network localhost` and got the error below:

```
(base) page Feb 27 4:54 ~/.../with typescript/my-first-dapp/smart-contract > npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.ts --network localhost
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at registerCustomInspection (/home/page/Desktop/pages/with typescript/my-first-dapp/smart-contract/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/index.ts:22:13)
    at /home/page/Desktop/pages/with typescript/my-first-dapp/smart-contract/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/index.ts:34:5
    at getRealTarget (/home/page/Desktop/pages/with typescript/my-first-dapp/smart-contract/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/util/lazy.ts:112:22)
    at Object.get (/home/page/Desktop/pages/with typescript/my-first-dapp/smart-contract/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/util/lazy.ts:185:26)
    at main (/home/page/Desktop/pages/with typescript/my-first-dapp/smart-contract/scripts/deploy.ts:28:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/page/Desktop/pages/with typescript/my-first-dapp/smart-contract/scripts/deploy.ts:43:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/page/Desktop/pages/with typescript/my-first-dapp/smart-contract/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/page/Desktop/pages/with typescript/my-first-dapp/smart-contract/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
```

what could be wrong here??
below is the code snippet I want to run:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");


async function main() {
  const StackUp = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("StackUp");
  const stackUp = await StackUp.deploy();

  await stackUp.deployed();

  console.log("stackUp deployed to:", stackUp.address);

  let adminAddr = await stackUp.admin();
  console.log("admin address:", adminAddr);

  await stackUp.createQuest("Introduction to Hardhat", 2, 600);
  await stackUp.createQuest("Unit Testing with Hardhat", 4, 500);
  await stackUp.createQuest("Debugging and Deploying with Hardhat", 5, 400);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: is it too hard to share the code in `scripts/deploy.ts`? would be able to answer such a question if you wanted to help?

Comment: @Yilmaz I have added `deploy.ts`

Comment: Please don't use a screenshot of code - post the actual code.

Comment: If you comment out 3 `createQuest` calls, do you still get the error? If yes, then comment out `stackUp.admin()` call

Comment: yes ser, it persists